# Country selection best practices

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a webstore in two currencies, each having a different shipping rate. What is the best way to send the user to the right store? Setting up a splash page and ask the user to choose his shipping country, get the country information through a popup, or routing through IP detection?

Comment: Are there any suitable extensions? Perhaps [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/module/2238/currency-auto-switcher)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with using IP detection and then when the page first loads suggest the country he or she is in.

On that "splash" page, allow them to pick a different country if the IP detection is incorrect and suggest other countries surrounding their country that was detected.

The reason I would allow the selection is because IP detection isn't foolproof and depends on many factors.

For example, they may be working in a remote office out of Dublin, Ireland but are connected through their company's network in New York, USA.

Hope this helps :)